# Alternative way(s) of structuring these objects in C# language

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, static

My goal is something along these lines:

```
// Defines members, for the "change-log" of the API, 
// if the interface has changed, the API has a new major version.
// For "automatically generating changelogs" (for major versions) of the API
interface IApp
{
    static string Name { get; set; }
}

// Internal class, not for usage outside of the dll
internal static class AppConfig
{
    internal static bool IsPublished;
}

// Public available members from the API
public static class App : AppConfig, IApp
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, there are a few wrongs in the structure above, based on C# language:

1. The interface cannot have static members
2. The class App is static, so it cannot inherit a static class
3. The AppConfig is static, so it cannot be inherited from
4. The class App is static, so it cannot have an interface

My current "solution":

```
public static partial class App
{
    internal static bool IsPublished;
}

public static partial class App
{
    public static string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which I wanted to add contracts/interfaces to... So, I would maybe end up with something along these lines, "wrapping" APP:

```
public static class App
{
    private static _App app;
    static App()
    {
        app = new _App();
    }
    public static string Name { get { return app.Name;  } }
}

internal interface _IApp
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class _App : _AppConfig, _IApp
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class _AppConfig
{
    internal static bool IsPublished;
}
```

This is long, tedious and boring. Three places to update insert a new member: Interface, _App-class (implementation) and in the static App-class (for API-users).

1. I want to achieve two things: A contract, interface, which defines all major changes from one version to another (read interfaces, print to change-log).
2. Making things that shall not be used for users of the API private (internal...).

The question? Anyone done something similar before, how did you solve it? Or talk me into forgetting the idea of a changelog based on interfaces... Because interfaces requires non-static objects, while I want static objects (at least on this particular object, it is static!).

PS: Atm. I read all public objects/members of the API to a log, which is now the "changelog". But starting on a new API, wanted to do something... different. :)

Edit: Note; I care about how the object looks on the "other side", it is an important thing. User of the API, to call App-members, shall be as simple as this (straight forward):
System.Windows.App.Name;
Which means the "outer class" (or however you want to look at it), is a static object.

Last note: I have several (12-15) objects of this "type", so I wanted a elegant structure, for all objects, all named similarly, so if you get to know one object, you know them all. Meaning: if one object has an interface, all others has one too. If one object is named "AppConfig", you can bet your life on that the other object also has a class named "OtherConfig". :)

Comment: Why static? Do you want to prevent several instances created? You can use singleton and make the classes non-static.

Comment: I do not want the singleton pattern. The class must be static, from a "user of the API point of view". Besides the "wrap"-solution, is more or less the singleton pattern...

Comment: You'll have to make-do with public static IApp TheApplication = new App();

Comment: public static IApp TheApplication = new App(); 
So you're saying I have to live with that? Hehe... I care for how users call my methods: System.Windows.App.Name; 
Guess the last example of "wrapping" _App into the "App"-static object is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to have different "flavors" of the same class. Each one shares some common functionality? If so, I would use an abstract class as the base instead of an interface. Then, derive the other classes from that one. Unlike an interface, the abstract class will allow you to provide implementations at the parent level (e.g.: saving the object to disk or database). You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx.

I also agree with Filkolev, this doesn't sound like something that you would want a static class for.

Comment: I do want the "outer object", the one that the users of the APi uses, to be static. So they can simply call:
System.Windows.App.Name;
Whether or not I make, for instance, the "AppConfig" (shared common functionality) abstract or not makes no difference in the structure of the objects. Although, in this scenario, it should be abstract. :P